# How Gödel's first incompleteness theorem can be used for proving statements true or false

Tags: set-theory, incompleteness

If Gödel's first incompletness theorem states
$$\exists S: g(S)=g(\neg P(g(S)))$$
Where $g$ is the Gödel numbering of the statement. Since there is a proof that this statement is true but has no proof, isn't that a proof in itself which means there is a proof for this statement, but that contradicts the premise of the statement. What is the reason why Gödel's proof of this statement isn't a contradiction

Thanks Josh

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338958/what-does-it-mean-for-something-to-be-true-but-unprovable) question help?

Comment: That is not the statement of Gödel’s incompleteness theorem.

Comment: @MarkSaving it's not quite but a similar statement, what is the full statement?

Comment: This sounds more similar to Godel's diagonal lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma

Comment: For a good explanation of Godel's first incompleteness theorem via Turing machines, I recommend this: https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=710

Answer (score 1):

Godel's argument is **conditional on** the consistency *(or more, depending on what argument/version of the Godel sentence you're using)* of the system in question. For example, first-order Peano arithmetic ($\mathsf{PA}$) **can** prove "If $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent then $X_\mathsf{PA}$" where $X_\mathsf{PA}$ is the Godel-Rosser sentence for $\mathsf{PA}$. However, $\mathsf{PA}$ **cannot** prove $X_\mathsf{PA}$ outright (unless $\mathsf{PA}$ is inconsistent in the first place of course).

You always need to be careful about **what is being proved where**. Keeping the specific system implicit creates the impression of a circle where there isn't one: the right way to pose Godel's theorem in a general setting is

> there is no computably axiomatizable consistent complete theory interpreting Robinson arithmetic

which is outright provable in, say, $\mathsf{PA}$ (the phrase "interpreting Robinson arithmetic" is rather technical, but basically it's a precise way of saying "sufficiently strong" and - to the best of my understanding - is fairly close to optimal). But this doesn't yield a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $X_\mathsf{PA}$ (or anything similar), since $\mathsf{PA}$ doesn't know that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent (we hope!).

---

Separately, your attempt to symbolize the incompleteness theorem has a serious issue: we don't need the sentence $X$ to literally have the same Godel number as "$X$ is not provable (in the system in question)," we just want $X$ to be *provably (in the system in question) equivalent to* its unprovability (in the system in question). This is a much more flexible criterion; see e.g. the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83155/can-we-find-strong-fixed-points-in-the-fixed-point-lemma-of-g%C3%B6dels-incompletene).